# Animation of Popup Screen Not Working SwiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, popup

I am attempting to popup a screen half way on pressing a button and then disappearing when either the button or the "X" on the popup screen is pressed.

The code below works fine except I want it animated and the animation does not work, the popup just appears and disappears. What is going on here?

```
import SwiftUI

struct PopUpViewToggle: View {
    
    @State var show: Bool = false
    @State var offset: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button("Button") {
                show.toggle()
                offset = show ? UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2 : UIScreen.main.bounds.height
            }
            if show {
                ScreenToggle(show: $show, offset: $offset)
                    .offset(y: offset)
                    .animation(.spring(), value: offset)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ScreenToggle: View {
    
    @Binding var show: Bool
    @Binding var offset: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Button {
                        show.toggle()
                        offset = show ? UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2 : UIScreen.main.bounds.height
                    } label: { Image(systemName: "x.circle.fill").font(.largeTitle) }

                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `show.toggle()` inside a withAnimation block.

```
Button("Button") {
  offset = show ? UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2 : UIScreen.main.bounds.height
  withAnimation {
    show.toggle()
  }
}
```